# How to request a OAuth 2.0 access token by Google GData API?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-data-api

How to request a OAuth 2.0 access token by Google GData API? Does this API support OAuth 2.0? It is seems OAuth 1.x API only in the [spec](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/authn/oauth/package-summary).

I already get the access token. Now, I would like to send the OAuth2 request by GData API. The error msg is: Error while validating OAuth2 request.

Does following parameter a correct Oauth2 request header: Header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken) ??

Comment: Yes, the authorization header for Bearer tokens has a format like this: `Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}`

Answer (score 0):

You first use any method you prefer (e.g. using the [google-api-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2) or directly using [REST](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)) to get an OAuth 2 access token, then you [set up your GData client library service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228212/gdata-java-client-oauth2-access-token-secret) with this access token and use it to call some API.

Comment: Thanks.  I already get the access token.  Now, I would like to send the OAuth2 request by GData API.  The error msg is: Error while validating OAuth2 request.  Does following parameter a correct Oauth2 request header: Header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken) ??

Comment: Please post a question with detailed information about your specific problem (including your source code and your authorizations steps, scope etc.)

Comment: my oauth2.0 resource server is powered by WSO2 ESB oauth mediator, the source code: http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.2AF/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.mediator/4.0.1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth/mediator/ . And I use HttpURLConnection to send my request header and token to resource server.

Comment: What does this have to do with Google's GData API?

Comment: I got a sample code for OAuth 1.0.  The sample code uses GData API to process the requests and responses of OAuth 1.0. But GData may not support OAuth 2.0 anymore.  So I am trying to make a bearer header to get a resource from ESB OAuth 2.0 proxy.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by using the GData API?

Comment: I am cleaning up my question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854261/elements-of-oauth-2-0-proxy-requesting-envlope-for-wso2-esb