# How to upload video to youtube with gdata in objective-c using access token

Tags: objective-c, youtube

Here is my codes, which can upload video to youtube successfully. It is using user name and password, but I am going to use access token instead.Thank you very much.

```
GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser
                                                             clientID:@"test"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoPath];
    NSString *filename = [videoPath lastPathComponent];
    GDataMediaTitle *title = [GDataMediaTitle textConstructWithString:strVideoTitle_];
    GDataMediaCategory *category = [GDataMediaCategory mediaCategoryWithString:strCategory_];
    [category setScheme:kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory];
    GDataMediaDescription *desc = [GDataMediaDescription textConstructWithString:strVideoDescription];
    GDataMediaKeywords *keywords = [GDataMediaKeywords keywordsWithString:strkeyWord_];
    GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
    [mediaGroup setMediaTitle:title];
    [mediaGroup setMediaDescription:desc];
    [mediaGroup addMediaCategory:category]; 
    [mediaGroup setMediaKeywords:keywords];
    [mediaGroup setIsPrivate:isPrivate_];
    NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:videoPath
                                               defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"]; 
    GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;
    entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
                                                          data:data
                                                      MIMEType:mimeType
                                                          slug:filename];
    SEL progressSel = @selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:);
    [service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:progressSel];
    gDataServiceTicket_ =  [[service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                       forFeedURL:url
                                         delegate:self
                                didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)] retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this topic :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228212/gdata-java-client-oauth2-access-token-secret, I solve this problem throuth modifying gdata.

Firstly, modify requestForURL function in file GDataServiceGoogle.m like below:

```
...
// add the auth token to the header if ([authToken length] > 0) 
{ 
//NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoogleLogin auth=%@", authToken]; 
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", authToken]; 
[request setValue:value forHTTPHeaderField: @"Authorization"]; } 
else if ([authSubToken_ length] > 0) 
{ NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AuthSub token=%@", authSubToken_]; 
[request setValue:value forHTTPHeaderField: @"Authorization"]; 
} 
return request;
```

Secondly ,in function youTubeService added :

//[service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:StrUserName_ password:StrPassword_]; don't need anymore

[service setAuthToken:@"my access token"];

Further more, I use the newest version gdata.